# How do I make an image stretch to fit inside of a div in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap fluid layout.  This is a snippet of my code

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="background-image:url('images/ball on sand.JPG'); background-size:100%;">
  <h1>Pelican Volleyball</h1>
  <p>The northshore's premiere outdoor volleyball organization</p>
  <p><a href="index.php?p=about" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

If I make my window too narrow, the image "ball on sand" will repeat.  I just want the height of my image to stretch to fit entirely in the hero-unit div.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `background-repeat: no-repeat` and `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `background-size:cover`

From MDN

> cover
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.